# sql server multiple column values in single column by building query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need your expert help in building sql query for concatenated values of multiple different column into one column value.

In my case I have Table1 which contains columns

`acid1, acid2, acid3, acid4, acid5` of type `VARCHAR` and also columns `clr_bal_amt1, clr_bal_amt2, clr_bal_amt3, clr_bal_amt4, clr_bal_amt5`

of type `NUMBER`  and `columns deposit_duedate1, deposit_duedate2, deposit_duedate3, deposit_duedate4, deposit_duedate5` of type `DATE`.

Now I trying to achieve output asin single column values something like this

`"table1.ACID1|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT1|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE1 
  table1.ACID2|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT2|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE2

  table1.ACID3|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT3|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE3
  table1.ACID4|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT4|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE4

  table1.ACID5|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT5|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE5" as FinalSampleVal .`

Comment: So you want to concat all columns and select that as single column right ?

Comment: What is your problem here? Something else than just converting the data into varchar?

Comment: I get's error "The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the '|' operator"  when I try to execute this like select table1.ACID1|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT1|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE1 table1.ACID2|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT2|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE2
 table1.ACID3|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT3|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE3 table1.ACID4|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT4|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE4
 table1.ACID5|table1.CLR_BAL_AMT5|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE5" as FinalSampleVal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to select all columns seprated by `|` and in single column. You need to convert all non `VARCHAR` values to the `VARCHAR` and then using `+` operator you can concat them in single column.For converting you can use the `cast`. [More about cast here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). And you may want to use the `COALESCE` also because if the any column value is null then it will return the null.[More info on coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

```
   SELECT COALESCE(table1.ACID1,'defaultvalue') + '|'
        + CAST(COALESCE(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT1,0) AS VARCHAR)
        +'|'+CAST(table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE1 AS VARCHAR) 
        +'|'+ table1.ACID2+'|'+CAT(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT2 AS VARCHAR)    
        +'|'+CAST(table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE2 AS VARCHAR) 
        +'|'+table1.ACID3+'|'+CAST(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT3 AS VARCHAR) 
        +'|'+CAST(table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE3 AS VARCHAR) 
        +'|'+table1.ACID4+'|'+CAST(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT4)
        +'|'+CAST(table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE4 AS VARCHAR) 
        +'|'+ table1.ACID5+'|'+CAST(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT5 AS VARCHAR) 
        +'|'+CAST(table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE5 AS VARCHAR) AS FinalSampleVal
   FROM 
       yourtable As table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting like below:

```
select table1.ACID1|cast(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT1 AS VARCHAR(MAX))|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE1
table1.ACID2|cast(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT2 AS VARCHAR(MAX))|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE2
table1.ACID3|cast(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT3 AS VARCHAR(MAX))|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE3 
table1.ACID4|cast(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT4 AS VARCHAR(MAX))|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE4 
table1.ACID5|cast(table1.CLR_BAL_AMT5 AS VARCHAR(MAX))|table1.DEPOSIT_DUEDATE5" as FinalSampleVal
```